# Search for all po files in a directory and its subdirectories and create a Hashmap containing the filepaths as value and its directory as key

Tags: java, directory, hashmap, java-stream, po

I want to search for all `.po` files in a directory and add them to a HashMap.

My directories looks like the following:

```
dir1\<any number of subdirs>\*_en_*.po
                             *_it_*.po
                             ...
dir2\<any number of subdirs>\*_en_*.po
.                            *_es_*.po
.                            ...
.
dirn\<any number of subdirs>\...
```

How can I represent/search these files with the help of java-Streams and `HashMap<String, List<File>>`, with `en/de/it.po` as a `List<File>` type and the respective directory root of these files `dir1\subdir-1\**\subdir-n` as a key?

I've tried the following solution from a similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62824848/10042081 but I wasn't able to manipulate the filter/groupings correctly in order to solve my problem.
I've also tried to use `listFiles()` + `isDirectory()` recursively in order to achieve the desired result, with no success.

Comment: You may want to show your attempt code, and tell the details about the problems that you are having with it

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've used the mentioned solution in the other post and tried to add/replace the filter with `.filter(p -> p.toString().endsWith("po")` which didn't work, because nested directories were not included. I didn't knew what I needed to change in order to get the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty simple using [`Files.find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#find(java.nio.file.Path,int,java.util.function.BiPredicate,java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...)) to walk a directory tree looking for matching files, and [`Collectors.groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function)) to convert that stream into the desired map.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String dir : args) {
            try (var files = Files.find(Path.of(dir), 256,
                                        (p, attr) -> p.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".po"))) {
                Map<String, List<Path>> po_files =
                    files.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getParent().toString()));
                System.out.println(po_files);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will give you a map where the keys are paths to directories, and the values are lists of paths to all the `.po` files in those directories.